# How to logout from app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have many Navigation Controllers. After logout i need to reach on first view controller. But Using `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]` I am not able to reach on first view controller. Please check screenshot for more information. Please help me to solve this issue. I want to logout from my app.

[image]

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: Which controller you want to show after login @chaaruu

Comment: `self.view.window.rootViewController = YourViewController`

Comment: @ParvendraSingh: I am searching for logout..First view controller(Language).

Comment: sorry after logout which controller you want to show ..and whats is the index number of that controller ....

Comment: @chaaruu  use it may it help you  ..  [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:NO];

Comment: call this line on your logout method .... it move on home page means login page

Comment: @ParvendraSingh: Sorry, but i already did this..it's pushing me on previous navigation controller..

Comment: then call a controller like a simple call .....

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an unwind segue.

In your Login View Controller put something like this...

```
- (IBAction)logoutUnwindSegue:(UIStoryBoardSegue *)unwindSegue
{
    // don't need anything here if you don't want but you might want to process the logout
}
```

Then from the view controllers that can log out you will be able to attach an action called "logoutUnwindSegue:" by CTRL dragging from the button to the green "Exit" icon at the bottom of the controller.

This will then pop back all the way to the login view controller.

Comment: I am using xib's too..my logout button is on xib..So, I am not able to find out this method..

Comment: May be this can help u---        [self.tabBarController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];